# How to import json report through automation using REST API and XRay for JIRA and Cucumber + Xray

Tags: selenium, automation, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-xray

I can manually import execution result(report.json) through jira and its giving proper status.But i want to achieve through automation i am unable to do so

[image]

How to do so

i tried using below curl command in terminal ..was unable to get expected result

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -u username:password --data @report.json http://myurl.net/rest/raven/1.0/import/execution/cucumber
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the curl request you showed is tailored for Xray on Jira server and from the screenshot you're showing, it seems that you're using  Xray on Jira Cloud. That requires that you have a token that you need to obtain first of all using another request.
If you're doing it by "hand" (i.e. from the command line), you would need to so something like:

```
token=$(curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data @"cloud_auth.json" https://xray.cloud.xpand-it.com/api/v2/authenticate| tr -d '"')
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $token"  --data @"report.json" https://xray.cloud.xpand-it.com/api/v2/import/execution/cucumber
```

My cloud_auth.json is something like:

```
{ "client_id": "215FFD69....","client_secret": "1c00f8f2c..." }
```

Please check in more detail the [authentication API](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Authentication+-+REST+v2) and the [endpoint for importing cucumber results](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Import+Execution+Results+-+REST+v2#ImportExecutionResultsRESTv2-CucumberJSONresults) (there are two actually) in the cloud.

Comment: {"error_description": "Invalid OAuth client credentials", "error": "unauthorized_client"} . i have written correct client id and secret key but me getting such errror'

Comment: That answer isn't from Xray. Are you making the HTTP request to the correct url, like https://xray.cloud.xpand-it.com/api/v2/authenticate ?

Comment: yes..same as you mentioned. also i tried curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{ "client_id": "32A27E69B0AC4E539C1401643799E8E7","client_secret": "d62f81eb9ed859e11e54356dd8a00e4a5f0d0c2a2b52340776f6c7d6d757b962" }'  https://xray.cloud.xpand-it.com/api/v2/authenticate

Comment: Try creating a new API key pair (client id + client secret) and try again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230129/discussion-between-sergio-and-suryaneel-varshney).